How to fix squeaky hardwood when the sub floor isn't the issue?
I have a house from the mid 70s with what I assume is original hardwood floors in the bedroom. There are some really bad squeaky spots, including about 10 square feet in the master bedroom.
Everything I see online talks about tightening up the subfloor to the joists, but that doesn't seem to be my issue. The subfloor is tight to the joists everywhere under the squeaky area. There's absolutely no room to drive in a shim, and I tried the break-away screws with no luck.
I assume this means it's the actual top level of wood that is squeaking. What can I try to remedy this?

If the squeaking is caused by friction between the floorboards, you can try applying a lubricant such as talcum powder, graphite powder, or WD-40 between the floorboards. This will help reduce friction and eliminate the squeaking.

That isn't usually where the squeak occurs; it's generally a lose nail running against wood or vice versa. And graphite used incautiously can make a hell of a mess; it has used as a lubricant but this is not one of them.
